# Is a finite product of fields an affine algebra?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $R$ be a commutative ring isomorphic to the product of finite number of fields each of which contains a copy of real numbers, i.e. $$R\cong \prod_{n=1}^k F_n$$ and for each $n$, $\Bbb{R} \subseteq {F_n}$. Can we find a ring homomorphism from polynomial rings $S=F[x_1,...,x_n]$ onto $R$?

PS. I only need to find a ring homomorphism in which it is only onto.

Comment: What is the field $F$? One of the $F_n$?

Answer (score 1):

No.

Let $k=2$, $F_1 = \mathbb{R}$, and $F_2$ be any field containing $\mathbb{R}$ that has greater cardinality than $\mathbb{R}$.

Let $S = F[x_1, \cdots, x_n]$. By using the usual methods of identifying such things, the following are equivalent:

- Homomorphisms $S \to R$
- A pair of homomorphisms $S \to F_1$ and $S \to F_2$
- A pair of homomorphisms $F \to F_1$ and $F \to F_2$, along with a selection of $n$ elements of $F_1$ and $n$ elements of $F_2$

Because we need a homomorphism $F \to F_1$ and because field homomorphisms are injective, this says that the cardinality of $F$ is no greater than that of $\mathbb{R}$.

However, this implies the cardinality of $S$ cannot be greater than that of $\mathbb{R}$. Since $R$ has greater cardinality than $S$, there cannot be a surjection $S \to R$.

Answer (score 1):

You can if and only if there exists a field $F$ such that each field $F_n$ has finite degree over $F$ (Zariski's lemma).